# Python Regex pattern matching digits and words question?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm having hard time creating a regex pattern and maybe you could help.

1.Target is to get only the result which is in BOLD and not the command with grep x.x.x.x?

```
var = "grep " +net+ "/mnt/hgfs/IRR/fgen.txt"
f2pat = re.findall(r'^([\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})/\d+',fgen)    
print ("FGEN Command: ",f2pat)
```

FGEN Command:  grep 223.253.0.0/20 /mnt/hgfs/IRR/fgen.txt
**223.253.0.0/20**

Now I do have two addresses in the output 1 is from the command itself second is the result(bold) and just want to match the result.

2. Target  is get the digits after the word member: AS**xxxxx**(BOLD)? 
   /mnt/hgfs/IR/FILE/as4431-customers-sc:members:    AS**28723**, AS3212

   fpas = re.findall(r'(^members:    AS)(?:\d{1,6})',xxx)
3. Target is to get/match the ip address(bold) after the work route:?
   RADB:  route:      **1.0.0.0/8**

   radbpat = re.findall(r'(?<=RADB:)(\S+ \S+)(?<=route)(\S+ \S+)(?:[\d]{1,3}).(?:[\d]{1,3}).(?:[\d]{1,3}).(?:[\d]{1,3})/\d+',who)

My regex patter doesn't work properly.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one, it appears that the subnet you want is located at the end of the string, so you can just capture exactly that:

```py
text = 'grep 223.253.0.0/20 /mnt/hgfs/IRR/fgen.txt 223.253.0.0/20'
result = re.match('^.+\s([\d\.\/]+)$', text).group(1)
# result = '223.253.0.0/20'
```

---

For the second one, it looks like you just only want to capture the first instance of AS**xxxxx**, so you can do:

```py
text = '/mnt/hgfs/IR/FILE/as4431-customers-sc:members: AS28723, AS3212'
result = re.match('^.+\b(AS\d+)\b.+$', text).group(1)
# result = 'AS28723'
```

---

For the third one, you can reuse the first solution:

```py
text = 'RADB: route: 1.0.0.0/8'
result = re.match('^.+\s([\d\.\/]+)$', text).group(1)
# result = '1.0.0.0/8'
```

Comment: Hi @MatiasCicero, Thanks for sharing.  Will study your code. also seem like example 2 doesn't work.. Can't able to match ASxxxx

Comment: tried using this but I'm seeing that all AS has been added..Cat end the pattern after getting the first AS from members:
ppat = re.findall("(?<=members:).+\s(?:AS\d+)",text2)
# result = 'AS28723, ASxxx, ASxxx'

Comment: @searching1 you need to use the boundary matches, and you are also using `findall`, which, as the name says, returns *all* the matches. What’s wrong with the regex I provided? Every element on that regex was put in place for a reason

Comment: From the regex pattern u've provided I'm having this traceback AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'group' ... While I tried using re.findall then your pattern but there's no match on its output. Thanks

Comment: using Findall how can I match only the AS# after the word members:? @MatiasCicero